# Laravel 7 User $user is not retrieving data

Tags: php, laravel-7

guys!
I have got some problems.
I have User and Page is kinda info about the user like Profile.
I have created User(using php artisan ui bootstrap --auth) and  PageController and Page (controller, model php artisan make:model and controller)

I have linked them using relations with one-to-one
What is my problem?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(User $user)
    {

        dd($user);
//        $user = \App\User::findOrFail($user);
//        dd($user->page()->title());
//        dd($user_id);
//        dd(User::find($user_id));
//        $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
        return view('pages.index', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
I don't get $user->page values using  public function index(User $user)
What am I doing wrong?

But when I do use :

```
$user = \App\User::findOrFail($user);
```

It gives me All User data with $user->page  too..
[image]

Comment: The relation isn't loaded automatically unless you use `with`. When you use `load` or try to access the relationship, it will load it.

Comment: @aynber where to put with? can you show the snippet ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading has the documentation on eager and lazy loading.

Comment: What do get if you run dd($user) ??

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit($user){

        $user = \App\User::find($user);
        $page = $user->page;


        if (Gate::denies('update', $page)) {
            abort(401);
        }

    }
```

I had to an instance of App\User mode to have all information.
and check with Gate.